# React State not getting updated properly in SetInterval Methods

Tags: reactjs, components, state

I've a button in the UI and in OnClick event handler, I've to run a set Interval timer.In Set Interval timer I'm checking for a condition and if the condition is met I'm updating the state,But It is not working properly.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function Counter() {
  let [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  let [gg, setgg] = useState(false);

  function countdownTimer() {
    console.log(count + gg.toString());
    if (count > 10) {
      setgg(true);
    }
    setCount((count) => count + 1);
  }

  function handleClick() {
    let id = setInterval(countdownTimer, 1000);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click</button>
      <h1>{count + gg.toString()}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");

// Second interval to demonstrate the issue.
// Fast updates from it cause the Counter's
// interval to constantly reset and never fire.
setInterval(() => {
  ReactDOM.render(<Counter />, rootElement);
}, 1
```

00);

In the countdownTimer function there is a console.log which is always printing "0 false" but the componenet in UI is updating to the correct number.

Could you please let me know why

1. the count is always '0' in the console.log
2. if count is always zero how does the state get updated corretct eveytime?
3. how can I print the correct value of count in the console.log() in the countdowntimer function.

code sand box link: https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-grass-7o4ms?file=/src/index.js

screenshot of Component updating correctly but the console.log is always zero.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

> 1. the count is always '0' in the console.log

Stale `count` state enclosed in `updfun` callback.

> 2. if count is always zero how does the state get updated corretct eveytime?

You used a functional state update so each update correctly updates from the previous state, ***not*** the state from when the callback was enqueued.

> 3. how can I print the correct value of count in the console.log() in the countdowntimer function.

Use an `useEffect` to issue a side-effect of logging state when it updates, and to also check the `count` greater than `10` to set `gg` state.

[image: Edit react-state-not-getting-updated-properly-in-setinterval-methods]

```
function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [gg, setgg] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(count + gg.toString());
    if (count > 10) {
      setgg(true);
    }
  }, [count, gg]);

  useEffect(() => () => clearInterval(timerRef.current), []);

  function updfun() {
    setCount((count) => count + 1);
  }

  function handleClick() {
    timerRef.current = setInterval(updfun, 1000);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click</button>
      <h1>{count + gg.toString()}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by Stale State? Could you please explain a bit more on that?

Comment: @Ravi Ah, I've always thought the term "stale state" was fairly self-explanatory. Basically the value of `count` is closed over (see [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)) from the render cycle the callback is saved in the `setInterval`. Think of it as a "snapshot" of what state was when the interval was created and it's called over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first set `count` value and then update it to state so your `countdounTimer` should be like

```
 function countdownTimer() {
    console.log(count + gg.toString());
    if (count > 10) {
      setgg(true);
    }
    setCount(++count);
  }
```

**OR**

```
 function countdownTimer() {
    console.log(count + gg.toString());
    if (count > 10) {
      setgg(true);
    }
    count=count+1
    setCount(count);
  }
```

[Click Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-timer-xx?file=src%2FApp.js) For demo

Comment: This only "works" because you are mutating (`++count` and `count += 1`) the state object, which in React, is a very bad habit to fall into. [Using State Correctly](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly)